# Create column with multiple ifelse()

Tags: r, loops, xts

```
require(xts)

data<- c(100,101,102,103,104,99,98,97,94,93,103,90,104,105,110)
date<- Sys.Date()-15:1
file<- xts(data,date)
colnames(file)<- "CLOSE"
file$high<- cummax(file$CLOSE)
file$trade<- ifelse(file$high*.95>=file$CLOSE, 1,ifelse(file$high*.9>=file$CLOSE, 2,0))
file

           CLOSE high trade
2013-07-05   100  100     0
2013-07-06   101  101     0
2013-07-07   102  102     0
2013-07-08   103  103     0
2013-07-09   104  104     0
2013-07-10    99  104     0
2013-07-11    98  104     1
2013-07-12    97  104     1
2013-07-13    94  104     1
2013-07-14    93  104     1
2013-07-15   103  104     0
2013-07-16    90  104     1
2013-07-17   104  104     0
2013-07-18   105  105     0
2013-07-19   110  110     0
```

The command for trade column I've given is when `.90*column high >= close`, the result in trade should be `2`.  I don't understand why the trade column doesn't equal 2 on 2013-07-14 and 2013-07-16.

i've got the answer for the problem mentioned above. my actual problem is something else. i thought i would do the research and get it done but still the problem persists.
i need the trade column to give me +1 or -1 every time close is  down by 5%, 10%, 15%... from high and when from respective close if again close is up by 10% it should give me -1.
when we add the +1 and -1 on any given date it should not be -ve or greater than 5.

Comment: The result is right, if x*. 95<y, then x*0.9<y also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trade column is never 2 because whenever `file$high*.9>=file$CLOSE` is `TRUE`, `file$high*.95>=file$CLOSE` is also `TRUE` and your first `ifelse` call is never `FALSE`.

Do something like this instead:

```
file$trade <- 0
file$trade[file$high*.95>=file$CLOSE] <- 1
file$trade[file$high*.90>=file$CLOSE] <- 2
```

Comment: can i do something with trade column where after i get my first 1 then all elements would be zero untill i get 2,

Comment: @AshishJalan That should be another question, with its own sample data :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think I prefer Joshua's approach for clarity, but the way to fix your `ifelse` clause is to swap around the tests. So change this:

```
file$trade<- ifelse(file$high*.95>=file$CLOSE, 1,ifelse(file$high*.9>=file$CLOSE, 2,0))
```

to this:

```
file$trade<- ifelse(file$high*.90>=file$CLOSE, 2,ifelse(file$high*.95>=file$CLOSE, 1,0))
```

P.S. Potentially using the ifelse's is quicker (when breaking down into three lines all the "2"s get set to first 0 then 1 before being set to 2). In your case where the "2" result is relatively infrequent, I'm sure the difference would be too slight to benchmark.